# The Following query gives me an error

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause, sql-like

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_channels` 
WHERE channel_id In ('implode(',',Select channel_id from users ))
```

Comment: Kick the implode part out

Comment: Is it a secret error?

Comment: At least tell us what the error is.  Also, improve your code formatting: highlight all your code and press the code button above the text input area. The code button looks like `{ }`

Answer (score 1):

Please note that implode() is a PHP function. It can't be used within a mysql query this way.

There's no need of this implode anyways. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM sales_channels 
WHERE channel_id IN (SELECT channel_id from users)
```

Another way would be using INNER JOIN.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM sales_channels INNER JOIN users
 ON sales_channels.channel_id = users.channel_id;
```

The above query will return those rows with matching channel_id from both tables.

You could look up the syntax of [MySQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) here.

Comment: in the channel_id in users are list of id's

Comment: Yes, I understand. You could have also joined these two tables using INNER JOIN.

Comment: the first id only will be displayed